# Query arg not available on init

Tags: query-variable

I'm adding my query arg as such:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'my_query_var';
    return $qvars;
});
```

And when I do:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    $string = get_query_var( 'my_query_var' );
    echo( $string );
});
```

It's not available, yet if I hook very, very late, like `loop_start`, it's there. What exactly am I missing? The string I passed is there if I inspect `$_GET`.

Answer (score 3):

The `query_vars` filter does not run until after `init`. The earliest hook you can use `get_query_var()` is [`parse_request`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_request/), which runs after `init`, but before `send_headers`, `wp`, `template_redirect`, and `template_include`.

Comment: What am I missing, then? A lot of plugins do their thing on `init` and at least to me, it seems that `GET` is extremely popular, yet it would make these plugins work weird...or so I think.

Comment: You're not missing anything. You just can't use `get_query_var()` that early. I bet if you looked at other plugins they're not doing that either. You question doesn't include any information on what you're even trying to do, so I can't tell you how to do what you want. Your question was asking why `get_query_var()` is empty, which I've answered. If you're trying to do something more specific, then that's what you should be asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of issues as well with firing the hook and parse_request didn't work but wp hook did.

It is run in the main() WP method in which the $query_args are passed to parse_request(), as well as when send_headers() , query_posts() , handle_404(), and register_globals() are setup.

```
add_action( 'wp', function () {
     if ( '' !== get_query_var('cat') ) {
       // prevent redirections
       add_filter( 'pll_check_canonical_url', '__return_false' );
   }
   else {
       wp_die('not cat');
   }
} );
```